# XCode Scene view loading model incorrectly

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit

I've loaded a model into my scene (.scn) and when zero-ing the model out, it seems to be at a 90 degree angle on the x-axis (even though the inspector says 0).

[image]

This is incorrect, but strangely when the running the scene on the emulator the model loads in the correct position.

[image]
Has anyone experienced this before? It's rather annoying.

Comment: Sketchup? Blender? view answer below.

Comment: This was exported using blender, thanks for the response. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! This is a common thing to experience.

Depending on where you made your model, blender, sketchup, 3dsmax, etc.
Some programs use a "Y-up Axis" that means that the Y axis is up. However, `SceneKit` uses a "Z-up Axis".

The reason it appears differently when running your app is because in your ".xcaccets" folder, or whatever it is called, you have "always convert to z-up axis" checked.

I'm not quite sure how to convert it before editing in Xcode's editor, but perhaps, you could use [write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscene/1523577-write%20write(to:options:delegate:progressHandler:)) to export the corrected version out of `SceneKit` for non-eye-sore Z-up editing.

Hope This helps!